# Python - How to move characters in string by X amount

Tags: python, string, position, character

In python how can I move characters in string by x amount?

For example lets say the input was "hello"

How can I move each character in the string by 1 so the output I get I get is:
"ohell"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use:

```
my_string = 'hello'
my_string = my_string[-1] + my_string[:-1]
print(my_string)
```

**Output**

```
ohell
```

`my_string[-1]` selects the last character in the string (`'o'`), and `my_string[:-1]` selects all of the string excluding the last character (`'hell'`).

To move by x amount you could use:

```
my_string = my_string[-x:] + my_string[:-x]
```

`my_string[-x:]` selects the last x characters in the string, and `my_string[:-x]` selects all of the string excluding the last x characters.